# Qual a vantagem de usar function(window, document, undefined)

Tags: javascript, closures

Notei a um bom tempo que muitas bibliotecas estão a usar algo como:

```
(function(window, document, undefined){
    //exemplo de script
    console.log(window, document);
})(window, document);
```

ou

```
(function(window, document, undefined){
    console.log(window, document);
}(window, document));
```

Isto realmente traz vantagem ao desenvolver algo como:

```
(function(){
    console.log(window, document);
})();
```

> Note: Se `undefined` é uma variável a normal e pode ser alterada `undefined = "new value";` o que impossibilitaria a comparação com `var a; if (a === undefined) { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De um modo geral usa-se funções IIFE desta maneira para salvaguardar que variáveis caiam no escopo global.

Uma IIFE é uma função que se auto-executa, e gera um novo escopo dentro dela própria.

Passar como parâmetro da função `window` e `document` não tem grande utilidade, mas tem uma função que é facilitar/optimizar na compressão do código.

Se houver muitas vezes no código dentro dessa função as variáveis `window` ou `document` então um compressor de JavaScript como o Uglify vai encurtar e dar uma letra a essas variáveis, dessa maneira minimizando o tamanho do ficheiro.

O caso do undefined é mais interessante.

Por vezes comete-se o erro de sobre-escrever essa variável. Ou seja é possível (em alguns Browsers) fazer `undefined = 20`. Nesse caso todas as linhas de código que usem `undefined` para verificar se uma variável está definida vão dar valores inesperados. Criando uma função com 3 parâmetros **mas só chamar/usar 2**  faz com que o terceiro receba o valor real de `undefined`. Assim, para browsers que permitem re-escrever `undefined` este truque re-estabelece o seu valor original.

A outra vantagem e razão para o undefined aí estar é o mesmo que em cima: para compressores de código poderem transformar *n* vezes a palavra de 9 caracteres "undefined" numa letra só.

Comment: Na verdade a informação sobre o IIFE está fora do escopo da minha questão, mas a sua informação sobre a parte de "comprimir de código" era a resposta ao qual eu necessitava saber. +1

Answer (score 1):

Sei que a pergunta é antiga, mas já que você linkou a mesma em uma resposta, vale adicionar alguns detalhes.

- é util passar os objetos desta forma para realizar testes.
- quando se está desenvolvendo em node, a variável `window` não existe. Neste caso é possível fazer algo assim:

  ```
  (function(window) {
      window.sayHello = function() {};
  })(typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : this);
  ```

Obs: este é o processo que o jquery utiliza.

A questão sobre o `undefined` serve para garantir que a variável representa realmente o valor `undefined` já que a mesma pode ser sobrescrita.

Comment: Obrigado, uma boa informação +1

Answer (score 0):

Eles usam mais pelo `undefined` mesmo, as vezes pode estar definida de alguma maneira e pode  atrapalhar o código.

**Exemplo**

```
undefined = 'foo';
var bar;
bar === undefined; // FALSE

(function (undefined) {
    var bar;
    bar === undefined; // TRUE
})();
```