# Por que copiar o método do prototype ao invés de usar diretamente?

Tags: javascript, protótipo

Eu fiquei confuso quando vi um código de determinada biblioteca javascript - o  `undescore.js`.

Não me lembro direito o trecho do código, mas foi algo parecido com isso que vi.

```
var filter = Array.prototype.filter;

var meu_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

filter.call(meu_array, function (value)
{
    return value % 2 == 0;
});
```

Ou seja, ele copia o método `Array.prototype.filter` para uma variável e, em seguida, chama essa cópia com `call`, para definir `meu_array` como contexto da chanada.

Mas, em contrapartida, por que não fazer com a função existente dentro do `array` diretamente?

```
meu_array.filter(function (value) {

    return value % 2 == 0;
});
```

**Atualização**: Encotrei trecho do [código fonte do undescore.js](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) que causou a dúvida

```
var ArrayProto = Array.prototype, ObjProto = Object.prototype, FuncProto = Function.prototype;
var
    push             = ArrayProto.push,
    slice            = ArrayProto.slice,
    toString         = ObjProto.toString,
    hasOwnProperty   = ObjProto.hasOwnProperty;
```

Existe alguma razão especial para fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu não tenho certeza, mas posso presumir que seja para "digitar menos" e facilitar a compactação do código, semelhante a esta situação:

- [Qual a vantagem de usar function(window, document, undefined)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45328/3635)

Lembrando que em loops se chamar algo como:

Será "lento":

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
     if (Foo.bar.test(i)) {
          //Algo escrito
     }
}
```

Se comparado a este (que é mais rápido):

```
var test = Foo.bar.test;

for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
     if (test(i)) {
          //Algo escrito
     }
}
```

Então os motivos são:

- Escrever menos no código
- Melhor performance na execução
- Facilitar a compactação dos scripts

Answer (score 3):

Arrays em javascript são erroneamente utilizados por alguns como arrays associativos, que nada mais são do que objetos.

```
// versao correta
var arrAssociativo = {};
arrAssociativo.minha_chave = 'meu_valor';

// versão errada (mas também funciona na maioria dos casos)
var arrAssociativo = [];
arrAssociativo.minha_chave = 'meu_valor';
```

Então suponha que alguém utilize um array associativo como na segunda forma e faça o seguinte:

```
var meu_array = [];
meu_array.push = 'surpresa :)';
```

Se você tentar chamar a função `meu_array.push` irá obter um erro pois a mesma agora é uma string. No entando, a função `Array.prototype.push` ainda está intacta.